# Kernel not responding to dynamic evaluation (10.4.1.0), Linux 64 bit

Tags: manipulate, warning-messages

I am running Mathematica 10.4.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit) and I run into Mathematica freezing when I try a simple manipulate statement such as in the help file.  I tried doing what was suggested in 2015 but that doesn't work (i.e. [**try Ctrl+Shift**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96698/204)).  I also tried `Mathematica -cleanstart &` in hope that resetting to "Defaults" may help.  But that didn't help.

I made a video recording of my computer screen to demonstrate this issue (~46 seconds) and it may be [**viewed here**](http://sendvid.com/scxx7h5l?secret=3185025e-d551-4ee1-98a5-36d95824433c).

To summarize, Manipulate functionality works within the "help pages" context but the same piece of code, when pasted into a mathematica notebook/window invokes the "kernel is not responding to dynamic evaluation".

**Edit 10/22/2016**
This occurs with Mathematica 11.x on Linux Ubuntu1 6.04 64 bit.  It drove me crazy when my `Manipulate` and `Animate` functionality wouldn't work 15 minutes before my Wolfram Tech Conference presentation 2 days ago.  I do not have a fix for this.

Is there a fix for this? Or must I just use still images in the upcoming Wolfram Tech conference ? ;)

[image]

Comment: Just tried it on 11.1 Debian Linux 64-bit and it worked fine.

Comment: Try running it with your laptop plugged in. Or set your battery settings to max power and then run it.

Comment: Do you have the Suggestions Bar disabled? If not, that is what I would first suggest. If the issue still persists at this point I would reach out to tech support and see if they can help.

Comment: @user6014 Suggestions bar disabled does work.

Comment: @drN You mean it fixed the issue? If so I'd still send it into support so they can further investigate

Comment: @user6014 Yes, it fixed the issue.

Comment: @drN happy to hear!